# How to make a rule for this?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
http://mysite.com/staticcategory/page_name
```

change to

```
http://mysite.com/category/page-name?post_type=question
```

How to be a rule for this?

Comment: how does the post_type get determined? Is that a fixed string?

Comment: `staticcategory` is fixed and `post_type=question` is fixed!

Comment: Your question is too obscure. Can you elaborate on how `staticcategory` is transformed into `category`, for example?

Comment: category is static too, just need to replace it `category` to `mystaticcategory` in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/staticcategory/(.*)$ /category/$1?post_type=question [R]
```